# Security Connection Form (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, security, connection

I'm currently making a feature on my form so that the user can't login multiple times from different tabs. I use a token which is then compared. If it's the same one the user doesn't go through the login and he arrives directly on the other page.

Here is what I have done so far :

```
ConnectionController

  public function VerifConnection(Request $request)
    {
        $programController = new ProgramController();
        $programs = $programController->GetProgramsFromBDD($request);
        $credentials = $request->only('Identifiant', 'Password');
        $user = User::where('Identifiant', $credentials['Identifiant'])->first();

        if ($user && Hash::check($credentials['Password'], $user->Password)) {
        Log::info('User found:', ['user' => $user]);
        Log::info('Password matches');
            $user->remember_token = Str::random(60);
            $sql = "UPDATE [User] SET remember_token = ? WHERE Identifiant = ?";
            DB::update($sql, [$user->remember_token, $user->Identifiant]);
            Log::info('token : ',  [$user->remember_token]);

            $user = User::where('Identifiant', $credentials['Identifiant'])->first();
            Log::info('Token:', [$user->remember_token]);

            Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
            $request->session()->put('remember_token', $user->remember_token);
            return redirect()->route('ProgramView');

        }

        Log::warning('Password does not match');
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
            'Identifiant ou mot de passe incorrect.'
        ]);
    }
```

````
Middleware/Authentificate.php

    protected function redirectTo($request)
    {
        if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('Connection');
        }
    }

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards)
    {
        $this->authenticate($request, $guards);

        $user = Auth::user();
        $sessionToken = $request->session()->get('remember_token');

        if ($user->remember_token !== $sessionToken) {
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect()->route('Connection')->withErrors([
                'Votre session a expiré ou vous vous êtes connecté ailleurs.'
            ]);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
    ```
````

```
web.php

Route::get('/Connection', [ConnectionController::class, 'Connection'])->name('Connection');
Route::post('/Program', [ConnectionController::class,"VerifConnection"])->name('verifConnection');
Route::get('/ProgramView', [ProgramController::class, 'GetProgramsFromBDD'])->middleware('auth')->name('ProgramView');
Route::post('/logout', [ConnectionController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');
```

The connection is done well, I get the token in the DB but the problem is that I return each time on the page of "Connection".

Comment: Are you using any Laravel packages for login (e.g. like Laravel UI, Laravel Breeze or Laravel Jetstream)?

Comment: @Coola no I don't use any package only the pre-made authentication of laravel with the middleware and "Auth".

Comment: Did you try dd($sessionToken) in Authentificate  middleware. I don't think it has a value

Comment: @KhangTran When I try a dd($sessionToken) and I don't make the connection, the dd is not even displayed....

Comment: it shows a blank page or it redirects to connection page?

Comment: @KhangTran I only have the first dd that appears on the white page, I just made an answer.